# Closure of the set of all matrices with no real eigenvalues in $M_2 (\mathbb R)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

What is the closure of the set of all matrices with no real eigenvalues in $M_2 (\mathbb R)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? What could be the eigenvalues of something in the closure?

Comment: Complex eigenvalues?

Comment: Well, the answer's there now...but the limit of a sequence of complex numbers can be real. And when the complex numbers come in conjugate pairs ($a \pm bi$), when this happens, you get a *pair* of identical real eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of a $2\times2$ matrix $A$ is $$x^2-tr(A)x+\det(A)$$

That its eigenvalues are not real means that $tr(A)^2-4\det(A)<0$. Therefore, in the closure we can only expect to have matrices with $tr(A)^2-4\det(A)\leq0$. The matrices with $tr(A)^2<4\det(A)$ are already the ones with non-real eigenvalues. So, let us see which matrices satisfying $tr(A)^2-4\det(A)=0$ are in the closure.

If $tr(A)^2=4\det(A)$ then $$4x^2-4tr(A)x+4\det(A)=4x^2-4tr(A)x+tr(A)^2=(2x-tr(A))^2.$$ This means that the matrix has only one real eigenvalue.

These are matrices of the form $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}ut&\pm u^2\\\mp t^2&-ut\end{pmatrix}$$
with $a,u,t$ real. Don't mind too much the form of the second matrix, what is important is that it has trace and determinant equal to zero. So, the terms in the diagonal add up to zero and their product is equal to the product of the elements in the antidiagonal.

Consider $$B_n=\begin{pmatrix}a&1/n\\-1/n&a\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}ut&\pm u^2\\\mp t^2&-ut\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $tr(B_n)=2a$ and $\det(B_n)=a^2+u^2/n+t^2/n+1/n^2$. Therefore $tr(B_n)^2<4\det(B_n)$.

We have that $B_n\to A$.

Therefore all matrices with one eigenvalue are in the closure.

Comment: You only proved $A \in cl(C)$.

Comment: @Asish No, read the beginning again. First we notice that the closure is included in the collection of all matrices with non-real or one eigenvalue. The ones with non-real eigenvalues are in the closure by definition, so it only remains to show that those with one eigenvalue are in the closure. This last part is   the meaty part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You might want to make use of the fact that the complex eigenvalues of a real matrix occur in conjugate pairs. For example, if $1-3i$ is an eigenvalue of $A \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$, then $1+3i$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: I havr no idea in what way this helps, to be honest.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez the idea should be that the property that the real parts of the two roots are equal is preserved in the limit, implying that if the limit has a real root it has only one root (or the two roots that are equal, if you want).

Comment: That tells us that the closure is contained in the set of matrices whose eigenvalues have the same real part (notice that this depends on a rather nontrivial fact: That the roots of a polynomial depend ccontinuously on the coefficients)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez for *quadratic* polynomials it seems not that hard to see the continuity of the dependence. I am not sure what you want to say with your first phrase, since yes what one gets is the closure is contained in the original set *and* the matrices with only one (real) eigenvalue. It remains to consider which of the latter ones one gets as a limit. // I do not argue this is the best hint possible. However, I do feel there is some relevant piece of information there.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I agree that it might not be the most practical hint, although it can certainly made to work. I changed the wording a bit so that I don't seem to be saying that this is the only approach.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint.* The coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of a matrix can be written in terms of the entries of the matrix, and the condition that that characteristic polynomial have no real roots can be written as an inequality involving its coefficients. Make this explicit.

Comment: Why the downvote on this useful hint?